# Amazon EC2 connect using curl

Tags: php, curl, amazon-ec2

I have free tier EC2 AWS instance, backend application is deployed using JBoss server on same. There is another frontend application developed in PHP deployed on another server(cPanel).
Issue is PHP application using 'curl' unable to get JSON response from EC2 instance server( returns 200 response but no data is returned). However when I try to connect to EC2 server by locally deployed PHP frontend application, works fine.
I have already created security groups and enabled 8080/80 inbound ports on EC2 instance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the curl options you are passing to get a response? Did you try curl -o?

Comment: I am using curl _init.. from my PHP page.

Comment: curl_init is just to initialize. You need to then redirect the output of curl_init to curl_exec as like below: ````$ch = curl_init( $json_url ); $result = curl_exec($ch);````